# Send WhatsApp Button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

how to send Button message to WhatsApp?
[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn1UQ.png)
[Or This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYmbl.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a WhatsApp sharing link on a website

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {  
    a {  
        display: none  
    }  
}
```

WhatsApp sharing Link Share to WhatsApp

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    a {
      display: none
    }
}
```

Comment: <html>   
<head>   
    <title> Add a WhatsApp sharing link on a website </title>   
</head>   
<style>  
    @media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {  
        a {  
            display: none  
        }  
    }  
</style>  <body>   
    <h3 style="color:brown"> WhatsApp sharing Link </h3>   
    <!-- create a link using anchor tab -->  
    <a href="whatsapp://send?text=This is WhatsApp sharing example using link"       data-action="share/whatsapp/share"  
        target="_blank"> Share to WhatsApp </a>   
</body>   
</html>